# The type or namespace name "MyBindingLib" does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have xamarin.ios binding project for ios library. When I reference it in some xamarin.ios project, it shows lots of errors like:

```
The type or namespace name "MyBindingLib" does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Is there any possible workaround to get rid of it? (Except using "build only" option in error list window, which is useless for the actual code)
It compiles and works successfully, though.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a bug I filed a while ago:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42448

If so, the workaround is to reference the binding project's .dll instead of the binding project itself. IOW, build the binding project and then add a reference to that .dll from your X.iOS project.

Comment: You also need to unload that project from the solution. But this works. Thank you! Hopefully they fix this bug soon.